# Displaying error messages for missing fields in a form all at a time

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with many fields. After I press the submit button without filling in the field details, I should display an error message for all fields at once below the field. How do I do it? Right now I'm using alert, but I don't want it. Below is my code for validation. Right now I'm just showing two fields: reg and vehicle owner. Want to display in red the error message as: `Please enter registration number below the field.` On submitting the form, the control comes to a function which has this below code.

```
if( reg1 == "" || reg2 == "" ||  reg3 == "" || reg4 == "")
{
    alert("Please Enter Proper Registration Number");
    return false;
}
else if(vRegisteredOwnerName == "")
{
    //alert("Please enter registered owner's name");
    document.getElementById("vRegisteredOwnerName").style.borderColor="#FF0000"

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Better go for `validationEngine` plugin, it does both the work of css and message displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Better create a new div element like

```
<div id='errorMsg'></div>
```

2) Instead of `alert()`, you can show the error message within the above `div` element.

```
document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML 
                   = "Please Enter Proper Registration Number";
```

Here is a short [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/we9gy/) and below is the full code.

```
validate = function () {
    reg = document.getElementById("reg").value;
    vRegisteredOwnerName = document.getElementById("vRegisteredOwnerName").value;
    errorModal = document.getElementById("errorMsg");

    if (reg == "") {
        errorModal.innerHTML = "Please Enter Proper Registration Number";        
        if (vRegisteredOwnerName == "") {
            //alert("Please enter registered owner's name");
            document.getElementById("vRegisteredOwnerName").style.borderColor = "red"
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery validation demo link :**

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

This plugin is best for jquery beginners.